# Bidding site plugin

Tags: plugins

I have to make the bidding site like odesk, freelancer type.
Is there any helpful plugin for job, contractor, user, project and payment management in wordpress as these are the main tasks of this project?

Secondly, building it in wordpress will be good or in a custom way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a plugin but a commercial theme, but you might want to check it out.

http://sitemile.com/products/wordpress-project-freelancer-theme/